# Call async functions in blocking context in Tornado

Tags: python, async-await, tornado

I want to implement a service based on web sockets in the Tornado framework. When a user closes a web socket, I want to notify the other users about this. However, `on_close` is apparently a blocking function and my `_broadcast(str) -> None` function is async.

How can I call this function anyway?

```
from tornado import websocket

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class SocketHandler(websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    async def open(self, *args, conns, **kwargs):
        logger.info(f"Opened a new connection to client {id(self)}")
        self._conns = conns

    async def on_message(self, message):
        logger.info(f"Client {id(self)} sent message: {message}")
        await self._broadcast(message)

    def on_close(self):
        logger.info(f"Client {id(self)} has left the scene")
        self._conns.remove(self)
        self._broadcast("something")  # TODO

    async def _broadcast(self, msg): 
        for conn in self._conns: 
            try:
                await conn.write_message(msg)
            except websocket.WebSocketClosedError:
                pass


app = web.Application([
    (r'/ws', SocketHandler)
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.listen(9000)
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution you're looking for is to use `asyncio.create_task` when calling the coroutine:

```
def on_close(self):
    logger.info(f"Client {id(self)} has left the scene")
    self._conns.remove(self)
    asyncio.create_task(self._broadcast("something"))
```

(the legacy Tornado version of this function is `tornado.gen.convert_yielded`, but now that Tornado and asyncio are integrated there's no reason not to use the asyncio version for native coroutines)

But for this particular problem, the use of `await` in your `_broadcast` function is not ideal. Awaiting a `write_message` is used to provide flow control, but `create_task` doesn't do anything useful with the backpressure provided by `await`. (`write_message` is fairly unusual in that it is fully supported to call it both with and without `await`). In fact, it applies backpressure to the wrong things - one slow connection will slow notifications to all the others that come after it.

So in this case I'd advise making `_broadcast` a regular synchronous function:

```
def _broadcast(self, msg): 
    for conn in self._conns: 
        try:
            conn.write_message(msg)
        except websocket.WebSocketClosedError:
            pass
```

If you want to be better able to control memory usage (via the flow control provided by `await write_message`), you'll need a more complicated solution, probably involving a bounded queue for each connection (in `on_close`, use `put_nowait` to add the message to every connection's queue, then have a task that reads from the queue and writes the message with `await write_message`)

Comment: I see. Thanks for this insight. So, the solution proposed by @acushner is actually the better one in this case. - just one thing, I don't understand what you mean exactly by "backpressure"

Comment: Backpressure is when you slow down the source of a stream (of data or events) to match the speed at which the destination can consume it. It's a good principle in general, but it's not clear it applies in this case - you can't slow down the rate of clients leaving the scene; it's just something that happens.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

i think a solution that involves using an `asyncio.Queue` should work for you.

i made a small class as a mock-up to test this out:

```
import asyncio
import time


class Thing:
    on_close_q = asyncio.Queue()

    def __init__(self):
        self.conns = range(3)

    def on_close(self, id):
        time.sleep(id)
        print(f'closing {id}')
        self.on_close_q.put_nowait((self, id))

    async def notify(self, msg):
        print('in notify')
        for conn in range(3):
            print(f'notifying {conn} {msg}')


async def monitor_on_close():
    print('monitoring')
    while True:
        instance, id = await Thing.on_close_q.get()
        await instance.notify(f'{id} is closed')
```

from there, you'll need to run `monitor_on_close` in the `ioloop` you get from tornado. i've never used tornado, but i think adding something like this to your `__main__` block should work:

```
    ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_callback(monitor_on_close)
```

Comment: Thank you, that's definitely an interesting approach. `on_close_q` just should be an instance member because I can have multiple `Thing`s (one per connection) apparently and I'm not very comfortable with splitting the code of `on_close` to multiple locations. Therefore, I was hoping for something like `ioloop.IOLoop.current().run(notify)`, for which I haven't found anything via searching the Internet.

Comment: no reason to be an instance var, it will be called on the instance as passed in to the queue. i'm sure there's a better solution out there, but this should do the trick if you don't find anything better.

Comment: Ok, you're right. Thanks. If there's no better solution, I'll take it.